# cv2 imshow not displaying image and locking up the kernel

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I run my code which is locking up my kernel. I'm in a jupyter notebook using anaconda. The kernel indicator (Python 3 (ipykernel)) circle is solid and stays that way. I uninstalled and reinstalled opencv-python with pip. I'm not sure what is(or isn't)going on. My file is in the same directory as my JNB (so, no file not found in directory issue)

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('galaxy.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(type(img))
print(img)
print(img.shape) # (1485, 990)
print(img.ndim) # 2 because grayscale

cv2.imshow('Galaxy', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the output I do get:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[14 18 14 ... 20 15 16]
 [12 16 12 ... 20 15 17]
 [12 13 16 ... 14 24 21]
 ...
 [ 0  0  0 ...  5  8 14]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  2  3  9]
 [ 1  1  1 ...  1  1  3]]
(1485, 990)
2
```

But no display of the image? Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

​

Comment: it's gonna be waiting in the waitKey call until you press a key or close the imshow window....

Comment: you're wrong about the shape. the shape is `(height, width)` or `(height, width, channels)`. that doesn't cause anything to "lock up", it's *irrelevant*, so I've removed that from your question. please review [mre]

Comment: I'm not seeing any imshow window available

Comment: please add output of `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` to your question ([edit]). relevant: the `GUI:` section.

Comment: if you don't see an imshow window at all, perhaps you installed a headless variant of `opencv-python`.

Comment: I see the GUI portion says: GUI: WIN32UI Win32 UI: YES VTK support: NO  I'm running 64 bit, I'm assuming the 32 refers to 32bit.

Comment: #Christoph Rackwitz I ran what you suggested. Got this for the GUI section:

GUI:                           WIN32UI
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

Comment: Have you tried running the program standalone?  Outside of Jupiter Notebook, that is.

Comment: "win32" just means windows (as opposed to windows 3.11 or anything). if that's there, but you still don't get an imshow window, something's very fishy. I would think that jupyter does something wrong.

Comment: #Christoph Rackwitz, I fixed it by adding imS = cv2.resize(image, (960, 540))  to the code. Not sure why this worked. Maybe Jupyter isn't setting a default value for some reason. If anyone has any thought or experiences with this,I'd love to hear it.

Comment: **probably** the window *does* show up, but it's **behind** your browser window... is it? check your task bar.

Answer (score 1):

This worked on jupyter notebook:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("galaxy.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: of course it did, it's using matplotlib for the displaying, not OpenCV, so any issue with OpenCV's GUI facilities is **sidestepped**